# Why does my HP Proliant DL380 G6 only use 6 out of 12 physical cores when my HyperV VM is under load?

Tags: windows, hyper-v, hp-proliant

When my HyperV VM (running Ubuntu 20.04) is under load on my HP Proliant DL380 G6 (running Windows Server 2016), only 6 of the 12 physical cores are only being used i.e. only 1 out of the 2 CPUs are being used. Below is a screenshot of my Task Mananger.

[image]

This is confirmed by ILO (below) as only Processor 2 enters a power state of P1.

[image: ![enter image description here]

My HyperV VM is the only VM on my machine and I have provisioned it with 24 virtual processes (1 for each logical core since my server has 12 physical cores and 24 logical cores). Below is a screenshot of the processor settings for my HyperV VM.

[image]

**I want my HyperV VM to take advantage of all 12 physical cores. How can I achieve this and why isn't the VM taking advantage of all the cores available to it?**

Note that when I run a multi-threaded workload on the host, all 12 physical cores are being utilised as expected (as shown below).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I remembered that my VM had "Dynamic Memory" enabled so I tried running the VM with "Dynamic Memory" turned off. After stress-testing the VM, all 12 physical cores lit up. Happy for anyone out there to extend this answer by explaining why this solved my issue.